# Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'principal') [ Identity ] [ ASP.net core ]

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I'm working on an `Asp.Net core` project, and I use `Identity` framework.

**Problem:**

Inside a Controller I try to get the current user information based on `User` (his type is `ClaimsPrincipal`) but I got a runtime error.

**What I try:**

That is my `Controller` code

```
[Authorize]
public class ServiceController : Controller
{

    private readonly UserManager<AppUser>      _userManager;
    private          RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
    private          AppUser                   _currentUser;
    private          AppRoles                  _currentUserRole;

    public ServiceController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;

        SetCurrentUser();
        SetCurrentUserRole();
    }



    #region Private Methods

    private async void SetCurrentUser()
    {
        var us = User;
        _currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    }

    private async void SetCurrentUserRole()
    {
        string currentUserRoleName = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(_currentUser).Result.FirstOrDefault();

        if (User.IsInRole(AppRoles.Admin.ToString()))
        {
            _currentUserRole = AppRoles.Admin;
        }
        else if (User.IsInRole(AppRoles.User.ToString())) 
        {
            _currentUserRole = AppRoles.User;
        }
    }

    #endregion


    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        return _currentUserRole switch
               {
                   AppRoles.User  => RedirectToAction("Services", "User"),
                   AppRoles.Admin => RedirectToAction("Services", "Admin"),
                   _              => RedirectToPage("Login")
               };
    }


}
```

**Where I got the error?**

The error happened in `SetCurrentUser` method, Visual Studio thrown this exception:

> System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. (Parameter
> 'principal')'

**Error screenshot:**

[image: Screenshot]

**Additional info:**

My project depends on `.Net 5`

Please any help to fix this issue?

Comment: Make sure `User` property is populated before you pass it into UserManager. It's only populated after the user is authenticated. So check if your authentication services are registered (Startup > ConfigureServices) and auth middleware is wired up (Startup class > Configure)

Comment: Yeah, I was the same doubts, but I didn't know how to configure it, can you provide me a solution or suggestion about what I should do or code to written

Comment: Are you using EF to store your users in a DB?

Comment: @HansDevel yes I do

Comment: How do the user Login?

Comment: @HansDevel he should login from a login page generated automatically by `Identity`, as credentials the user should enter his username and password to login, and for login in back-end `Identity` already prepared the login `razor` page back-end

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `User` and `HttpContext` are not set yet (still `null`) in the controller's constructor. If you want to access it, try injecting the `IHttpContextAccessor` into the constructor like this:

```
public ServiceController(UserManager<AppUser> userManager, 
                         RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
                         IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor){
    var user = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
    //now pass the user above around to use it instead of basing on the property User
    //...
}
```

However that way is not every standard especially when you need to call `async` methods in the constructor, which should not be done at all. Your methods are even declared using `async void` which should be absolutely avoided. Actually what you want is automatically make some info available ***before the action being executed***. That's the perfect fit for an `IActionFilter` or `IAsyncActionFilter` (here using the async filter is better because you're going to call async methods in there). Because the info made available right in the controller (as properties/fields) so it will be more convenient to override the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method of the controller instead of using the filters I've mentioned. Using the filters in this case may require you to share the info around (such as via `HttpContext.Items` or request feature ...) which is a bit inconvenient.

Here's how you should do it:

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
   await SetCurrentUserAsync();
   await SetCurrentUserRoleAsync();
   await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}

//adjust your methods
private async Task SetCurrentUserAsync() { ... }
private async Task SetCurrentUserRoleAsync() { ... }
```

That's all, remember to remove your equivalent code in the constructor.

Comment: When refactoring to `SetCurrentUserRoleAsync`, remember to use `await` on `_userManager.GetRolesAsync(_currentUser)` instead of getting `Result` as in your old code.

Comment: This is a great comment and answer I have just one question in my constructor should I call `SetCurrentUserAsync` and  `SetCurrentUserRoleAsync` or just calling `OnActionExecutionAsync` and massive thanks

Comment: @DEV no calls in the constructor (as I've mentioned at the end of the answer), just use the code I posted.

Comment: Massive thanks' bro this is very helpful and informational answer